# Kafka Consumer - Point to specific offset in Spring boot Kafka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm trying to seek the offset to some specific offset. It seems I need to use seekToTimestamp and there is no seekToOffset or something. I've research a lot but couldn't find exact implementation of the code. For now I have to consume previous event which is already in topic that's why I've used:

```
topicPartitions = {@org.springframework.kafka.annotation.TopicPartition(topic = "some_topic",
            partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0"))}
```

But I have no idea how I can make it. Point listener to specific offset and start from there?

I would be grateful if anyone can help me!

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Builder
public class KafkaConsumer extends AbstractConsumerSeekAware {

    private final Optional<Long> seekToTimestamp; 

    @KafkaListener(id = "some_id", topicPartitions = {@org.springframework.kafka.annotation.TopicPartition(topic = "some_topic",
            partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0"))}) 

    public SomeAvroClass listen(SomeAvroClass someAvroClass) throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        log.info("Consuming event from Kafka" + someAvroClass);  
        log.info("BEFORE Seek : " + someAvroClass.getCode())); 
        KafkaConsumer.builder().seekToTimestamp(Optional.of(System.currentTimeMillis()- 6_000_000));
        log.info("AFTER Seek : " + someAvroClass.getCode())); //result is same as BEFORE
        return someAvroClass;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what is `KafkaConsumer.builder()`, but there indeed an API to seek to arbitrary offset in the `KafkaConsumer`:

```
/**
 * Overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use on the next {@link #poll(Duration) poll(timeout)}. If this API
 * is invoked for the same partition more than once, the latest offset will be used on the next poll(). Note that
 * you may lose data if this API is arbitrarily used in the middle of consumption, to reset the fetch offsets
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the provided offset is negative
 * @throws IllegalStateException if the provided TopicPartition is not assigned to this consumer
 */
@Override
public void seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset) {
```

The `AbstractConsumerSeekAware` delegates there via its `getSeekCallbackFor(TopicPartition topicPartition)` and then:

```
    /**
     * Perform a seek operation. When called from
     * {@link ConsumerSeekAware#onPartitionsAssigned(Map, ConsumerSeekCallback)} or
     * from {@link ConsumerSeekAware#onIdleContainer(Map, ConsumerSeekCallback)}
     * perform the seek immediately on the consumer. When called from elsewhere,
     * queue the seek operation to the consumer. The queued seek will occur after any
     * pending offset commits. The consumer must be currently assigned the specified
     * partition.
     * @param topic the topic.
     * @param partition the partition.
     * @param offset the offset (absolute).
     */
    void seek(String topic, int partition, long offset);
```

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#seek

**UPDATE**

Some possible listener for arbitrary seek:

```
@Component
public class Listener implements ConsumerSeekAware {

    private final ThreadLocal<ConsumerSeekCallback> seekCallBack = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "some_topic")
    public void listen2(String data,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        
        if (SOME_CONDITION) {
            this.seekCallBack.get().seek(topic, partition, 101);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        this.seekCallBack.set(callback);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Artem, Thanks for your response.
`KafkaConsumer.builder()` is from Lombok so calling the constructor and the method to seek.
I've seen those documents before but looking for some real example which works for my specific situation! Does that make sense?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Artem for that but it didn't work. There are messages already in topic and I try to re-consume them. I can reset the offset to 0 and start from begining with this: @KafkaListener(id = "some_id", topicPartitions = {@org.springframework.kafka.annotation.TopicPartition(topic = "some_topic",
            partitionOffsets = @PartitionOffset(partition = "0", initialOffset = "0"))}) 
But when I removed it (or even with it) and used your example it didn't consume any message!